# Linux/BSD: How can I call a program/script ignoring/bypassing the timeout command?

Tags: multithreading, timeout

This is my **script**:

```
$ cat LongRun.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "This line will obbey the timeout command and stop"

# This line below needs to run until it finishes:
dd if=/dev/zero of=zerofile.txt bs=1M count=400

echo "More lines that can be stopped"
```

When **running** it:

```
$ ./LongRun.sh
This line will obbey the timeout command and stop
400+0 records in
400+0 records out
419430400 bytes (419 MB, 400 MiB) copied, 31.3204 s, 13.4 MB/s
More lines that can be stopped
```

And the **results** are:

```
$ ls -la zerofile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis 419430400 Dec 21 10:47 zerofile.txt
```

But, when running it **through** `timeout` :

```
$ timeout 2s ./LongRun.sh
This line will obbey the timeout command and stop
$ ls -la zerofile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis 108195840 Dec 21 10:48 zerofile.txt
```

I want the full resulting file, so the `dd` line should **not be stopped** and create a complete 400MiB file:

How can I do this on Linux/FreeBSD?

**Tested** (without success) until now:

- `nohup dd if=/dev/zero of=zerofile.txt bs=1M count=400 &`
- `nohup $(dd if=/dev/zero of=zerofile.txt bs=1M count=400) &`
- `nohup $(dd if=/dev/zero of=zerofile.txt bs=1M count=400 &) &`
- `dd if=/dev/zero of=zerofile.txt bs=1M count=400 ; disown`
- `setsid dd if=/dev/zero of=zerofile.txt bs=1M count=400`

> (My mistake: the `setsid` method seems to work OK. Sorry everybody.
>   See my answer)

Comment: Can you try with `setsid setsid dd ...` and see if it helps?

Comment: Both `setsid setsid dd ...` and `setsid setsid dd ...` working. My mistake. Thanks you, @rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:

They both **work**:

```
setsid setsid dd ...
setsid dd ...
```

I performed the tests incorrectly. 
I have edited original question to reflect.
Sorry.